# Автоматически инициализировать составной тип данных нулями

Tags: haskell

Здравствуйте!
Есть составной тип данный MemberStat, в нем может быть много полей. Мне нужно инициализировать все поля данного типа нулями.

```
data MembersStat = MembersStat { hiddenStat      
                                ,deactivatedStat     
                                ,workStat       
                                ,schoolStat       
                                ,universityStat 
                                ,notFilledStat :: Int

                           } deriving (Show)
```

В данный момент делаю так:

```
emptyStat ::MembersStat
emptyStat = MembersStat {hiddenStat      = 0
                        ,deactivatedStat = 0 
                        ,workStat        = 0
                        ,schoolStat      = 0
                        ,universityStat  = 0
                        ,notMaried       = 0
                        ,notFilledStat   = 0

                    }
```

Но было бы удобнее записать как-то так:

```
emptyStat :: MembersStat
empytStat = MembersStat {0}
```

Есть ли способ автоматически инициализировать поля нулями, без явной установки значения каждому полю?

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос вот таким образом

```
 emptyStat :: MembersStat 
 emptyStat = empty
```